# res.redirect() not working for me in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to POST a request for /draft and create a new "draft" / update an existing one in my database. after that I want to instantly redirect to the /draft?id=RELEVANT_ID_HERE page.

this is my current POST request function:

```
app.post('/draft', function(req,res){
var id = req.query.id;
var postTitle = req.body.head;
var article = req.body.article;

if(id){
    db.postCatalog.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {title:postTitle, inShort:article.substring(0,100), content:article}, function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            return handleError(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
            res.status(200).redirect('/draft?id='+id);
        }
    });
}
else{
    id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });

    new db.postCatalog({title:postTitle, 
                    _id:id, 
                    author:'temp', 
                    AuthorID:2, 
                    date:'2/3/12', 
                    inShort:article.substring(0,100), 
                    content:article ,
                    published:false
                }).save(function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        return handleError(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(data);
                        res.status(200).redirect('/draft?id='+id);
                    }
                });
}
});
```

so, everything works except for the redirect. I am getting the correct GET request in the node console, but nothing happens in the browser.
[image: node console log]

this is the code for the GET request:

```
app.get('/draft', function(req,res){
var id = req.query.id;
if(id){
    db.postCatalog.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, post){
        if(err) {
            return handleError(err);
        }
        else{
            if(post){
                console.log(post);
                res.status(200).render('editDraft.hbs', {post: post}); 
            }
            else{
                routes._404(req,res);
            }
        }   
    });
}
else{
    console.log('creating new draft');
    res.status(200).render('editDraft.hbs');
}
});
```

I am using Express and Mongoose. view engine is Handlebars.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try returning status 301 or 304 instead of 200. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Same issue. Have you resolved this? I am getting 

127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 01 Dec 2013 04:19:07 GMT] "GET /profile/12345 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost:3004/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36"

But page never actually refreshes

Comment: nope. keep getting the same result no matter what I try.. and I keep finding examples of people doing the same thing only it works for them.. this is pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

I think the status 200 is throwing you off. Try using a 302 and it should work.

```
res.writeHead(302, {
    'Location': '/draft?id='+id
});
res.end();
```

Comment: I have tried doing this with different status code, writeHead/end, redirect with/without status, render with/ without status... but nothing seems to work. I keep getting the GET 200 message in the console with no actual redirect in the browser.

Comment: @omerkarj You are probably doing an AJAX POST, which means you cannot do a redirection. You'll have to handle it yourself client side. Checkout the following link for further details:  [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570301/res-redirect-from-post)