# How to redirect from nodejs backend to react frontend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So i make a request to this nodejs route: http://localhost:4000/api/v1/dev/confirmuserReg, if everything goes well, I want to redirect from the backend to my frontend app (react app) at this route: http://localhost:3001/signup?Account_activated=yes

```
if(status == "success" && message == "everthing_went_well"){
    //Activate users account in login service (i.e login table)
    const { Lstatus, Lmessage } = await post_fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3033/api/v1/dev/update_users", Tvalue)
    if(Lstatus == "success" && Lmessage == "everthing_went_well"){
        res.redirect(200, "http://localhost:3001/signup?Account_activated=yes")
    }else{
        //do other things...                    
    }
}
```

But instead of redirect to the frontend, it stays on the same page but prints the link which I intended to redirect to.
[image]

If I click on this link, it then takes me to the page I wish to redirect to.

I am certain I am doing something wrong. I suspect that maybe it is not possible to redirect from the backend to the frontend. Please how do I achieve redirect to the frontend url from the nodejs app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [res.redirect() not working for me in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058356/res-redirect-not-working-for-me-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because you are using status code 200 while redirecting. Instead, you should use a valid redirecting HTTP status code (e.g. 301 for a permanent redirect or 302 for a temporary redirect).
For more understanding you can refer to [this](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect)