# Node.js Page Redirect on AJAX login? With a function call after redirect?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, redirect, express

The '/stories' page is user-specific and requires valid login credentials.

Validation is accounted for with node, server-side, and properly logs before the redirect, but does not redirect to the stories page..

This seems to be because "[You can't make a redirection after an AJAX. You need to do it yourself in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570301/res-redirect-from-post)", but the code in the first answer to this question seems somewhat incomplete..for the succcess call..

Also, how can a subsequent function (refreshStories) be called on success after the redirect?

Here's the AJAX:

```
if (loginUsername.length != 0) {
  console.log('there is a login: ' + loginUsername);
    // make an ajax call
    $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    data: AjaxLoginData,
    type: 'post',
      url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/users",
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
          if typeof data.redirect == 'string'
              window.location = data.redirect
      success: refreshStories,
      error: foundError
    });
```

Node.js + Express4

```
router.route('/users')

    // log in a user (accessed at POST http://localhost:4200/api/v1/users)
    .post(function(req, res) {

      var username = req.body.loginUsername;
      var password = req.body.loginPassword;

      authenticateUser(username, password, function(err, user){
      console.log('authenticate user..');
        if (user) {
          console.log('yes user');
          // subsequent requests will know the user is logged in
          req.session.username = user.username;
          console.log('set session username to: ' + req.session.username);

          // res.redirect('/stories');
                res.send({redirect: '/stories'});
          console.log('user logged in .. redirect to stories');

        } else {
          console.log('user authentication badCredentials error..');
          res.render('index', {badCredentials: true});
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if (loginUsername.length != 0) {
  console.log('there is a login: ' + loginUsername);
    // make an ajax call
    $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    data: AjaxLoginData,
    type: 'post',
      url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/users",
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
          if (typeof data.redirect == 'string')
              window.location.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + data.redirect);
      error: foundError
    });
```

> window.location.replace(...) will best simulate an HTTP redirect 
>   [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript/506004#506004)

For your 'refreshStories' stuff, you should just refresh Stories when you go to '/stories'

Comment: This line `success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->` logs a syntax error.. and I thought it looked unlike javascript, but I pulled it from the linked post..

Comment: I was assuming you use CoffeeScript. Isn't that the case ? If you're not using CoffeeScript, the correct syntax would be `success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){...}`

Comment: Ah, no.. javascript/jquery/handlebars/express/node.js