# Redirecting POST to GET after Database Addition

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose and Express.js .

My Post request looks like this :

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {

        var uname = $('#username').val();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var json = {
            user_name: name,
            user_username: uname,
        };
        $.post("/saveprofile", json, function(data, error, xhr) { 
          if(!err)   
            window.location.href = "/feed";       
        });
    });
```

This is how I'm handling the request :

```
app.post('/saveprofile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res)  {

    var username = req.body.user_username; 
    var uname = req.body.user_name;

   User.findOne({$or:[{"facebook.email":req.user.facebook.email},{"local.email":req.user.local.email}]}, function (err, user){
      user.name = uname;
      user.username=username;
      user.save();
      res.send({redirect: '/feed'});
})
});
```

My documents get added into the db successfully but what I want is, when that happens it should redirect to a new page `/feed` . The above snippets mention 2 methods I've tried. But I've got no result . It doesn't redirect !

Edit:

Testing with exception handling gives `undefined`

```
app.post('/saveprofile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res)  {

    var username = req.body.user_username; 
    var uname = req.body.user_name;
try{
   User.findOne({$or:[{"facebook.email":req.user.facebook.email},{"local.email":req.user.local.email}]}, function (err, user){
      user.name = uname;
      user.username=username;
      user.save();
      res.redirect("http://stackoverflow.com")
  });
 }
 catch(ex){
  console.log(ex) ;
 }
});
```

Edit 2 :
I tried a sample request ...even it doesn't seem to redirect !

```
app.post('/test', isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    res.redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
})
```

Comment: Try replacing `res.send({redirect: '/feed'});` with `res.redirect('http://stackoverflow.com');`. Are you getting redirected to so ?

Comment: BTW is your data getting updated ? 
It can be only reason both redirection fails.

Comment: data is getting updated..yes !  redirect doesnt work !

Comment: Try surrounding your `findOne` with try..catch as `try { //findOneCode } catch (ex) {console.log(ex)}`. See anything pops in server console.

Comment: it gives `undefined` !

Comment: What exactly you getting in console, just `undefined` ?

Comment: yes ! exactly ! seems funny now :p

Comment: Something line number or anything ?
Better if you can share screenshot

Comment: I am sorry ! Im under an NDA .

Comment: Okay , Try printing content of req.user in console. `console.log(req.user);`.
Before `try...catch` block.

Comment: Its shows the collection properly ! no issues in that !

Answer (score 1):

**You can't make a redirection after an AJAX. You need to do it with Javascript**.

So here is how we can do it,

Post request :

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {
        var uname = $('#username').val();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var json = {
            user_name: name,
            user_username: uname,
        };
        $.post("/saveprofile", json, function(data, err, xhr) { 
          if(!err)   
            window.location.href = data.redirect;       
        });
    });
```

Server

```
app.post('/saveprofile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res)  {

    var username = req.body.user_username; 
    var uname = req.body.user_name;

   User.findOne({$or:[{"facebook.email":req.user.facebook.email},{"local.email":req.user.local.email}]}, function (err, user){
      user.name = uname;
      user.username=username;
      user.save(function(err){
          if(!err)
              res.send({redirect: '/feed'});
    });
})
});
```

[Link to Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11574444/923426)

Comment: this seemed pretty impressive . however its still not redirecting !

Comment: Try prinitng err of user.save to console.

Comment: man ! ill close this . Im fed up . theres no error ! lol ! thanks for your help !

Comment: If no errors then you should have got redirected. Okay i will stop. GL

Answer (score 0):

Try `res.redirect()`  instead :

```
res.redirect("/feed");
```

Comment: I don't know if it's because you didn't post all your code, but it looks like you're missing a closing bracket and parenthesis, try fixing that?

Comment: edited ! i forgot to paste the parentheses in the snippet

Comment: btw why isnt the client side JS working ! cant figure it out

Comment: Have you checked your browser console? You're checking if `err` exists but you've called it `error` when you define your function.

Comment: console's empty after correcting error spelling . still no redirect !