# res.redirect does not redirect to url, doesn't show an error either

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

On click of a button I send a post request to express through angularjs. In express' `post`, I redirect to another url. But nothing happens.

When I give a non-existing url, in the console I see a 404 error. When I give a correct existing url, it does absolutely nothing. Doesn't show any error either.

The express code:

```
   app.get('/login',function(request,response){ //the file sent when /login is requested
    response.sendFile(__dirname+"/staticFolder/view/login.html");
})

    app.post('/loginCheck', function(req, res, next) { //called by angular controller when button clicked

      res.redirect('http://localhost:4000/'); //supposed to show index.html
    });
    app.get('/',function(request,response){
        response.sendFile(__dirname+"/staticFolder/view/");
    })
```

The controller:

```
    .controller('loginController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.login=""
    $scope.password="";

    $scope.mysqlError="";

    $scope.loginFunc = function(){


        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'/loginCheck',
            data:{
               login: $scope.login,
               password: $scope.password
            }
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {

        if(response.data=='invalid'){
            $scope.mysqlError="mysqlError";
        }

        });

    }
})
```

Comment: response.sendFile(__dirname+"/staticFolder/view/"); add some view file which you want to render after /view/

Comment: @owaishanif786.i tried it. it still does nothing.

Comment: what did you see when you acess `http://localhost:4000/` on your pc ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan. i can see the `index.html` when I go to `http://localhost:40‌​00/`

Comment: your app has already listened in port 4000 so just do `res.redirect('http://localhost');`, then test a again.

Comment: try to redirect some other page like res.redirect("http://www.google.com");

Comment: @owaishanif786. in the console it says `GET http://localhost:4000/google.com 404 (Not Found)` when i do  `res.redirect("google.com");`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan. it didn't work..

Comment: try full url redirect res.redirect("http:/‌​/www.google.com");

Comment: @owaishanif786. that didn't work either

Comment: ah, localhost is a default url  for node, so try `res.redirect("/");` it will redirect to home page.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan. that's the first thing I tried..i then tried with `localhost`. nothing works. is it possible to redirect from a `post`?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan. ok i tried it now. I get `angular.js:12011 POST http://localhost:4000/ 404 (Not Found)`. But when I try to go to `http://localhost:4000/ ` by typing in address bar, I get the index.html. When I do it like in the link you gave, I get 404 error for the same url

Comment: Perhaps follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570301/res-redirect-from-post

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan. i have to send a response and show other page using angularjs based on the response. thanks a lot for trying to help :)