Node.js redirect to login.html if not logged
Is it possible to redirect the user to login.html from backend using node.js (v18.16.0) and express.js (v4.18.2)?
This is my current code.
const userList = require('./routes/userList');

app.use(session({
    secret: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex'),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.isLoggedIn)                 
        return res.redirect('https://mysite/login/login.html')
    else         
        next();
})

app.use('/userList', userList);

What I want now is that if I try to reach a webpage and I'm not logged in (e.g. userList.html), node.js must redirects me to the form login.
userList.html on load makes an ajax post request (with jQuery v3.7.1) to the same node.js server to the endpoint /userList
What I would expect is that object req.session.isLoggedIn is undefined and so it would redirect to https://mysite/login/login.html
Here what actually happens.
requests done when I load userList.html
login.html is the first request done (excluding json configs files) and the response is its html code.
endpoint /userList is on status 304 and still pending
Finally, the webpage does not redirect to login.html but it remains https://mysite/users/userList.html
What am I doing wrong? Why do I see login.html in requests and it does not redirect to?
Thank you.
I tried to use the function res.sendFile() instead of res.redirect() but it does not change anything.

You can't make a redirection from an AJAX call. You will have to do it from your client-side. This answer gives you an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11574444/4183699.
